# mkfs ext4 on Debian 11 - inconsistent resize_inode results on filesystem creation

Tags: debian, ext4, mkfs, resize2fs

I am running Debian 11 with all current updates (kernel 5.10.0-18 and e2fsprogs 1.46.2-2).

I have been mkfs.ext4 some filesystems on various volumes - with lvm2 on top of mdraid, fwiw.
Specifically, the system has a separate root fs (on a separate drive, <<1TB) and a single mdraid device which is the only pv in the single vg the system hosts.
In this vg, there are two lvs, a larger one (36TB) and a smaller one (<1TB).

Upon creation of the root fs before mdraid/lvm2 operations and of the smaller lv fs after mdraid and lvm2 were set up, I get expected results with resize_inode enabled on the filesystem (together with the other expected defaults from `/etc/mke2fs.conf`).
However, in the same context, if I use the exact same commandline (with devices changed) to create a filesystem on the larger lv, the filesystem creates correctly... *without* resize_inode .
FWIW, the creation options include `-m 0 -E stride=nnn,stripe_size=nnn` for BOTH filesystems. Explicitly adding `-O resize_inode` has no effect.
I have never encountered this before and I understand that there is no good reason, on modern linux, to NOT have resize_inode on an ext4 filesystem - not having it may eventually limit the extent of future resize2fs operations, which I really do not want.

Is there a way around this? Is it expected behaviour? I could 'artificially' create a small lv, thereby insuring the feature, then resize2fsing it to full size, but it seems... rather silly.

Answer (score 2):

Theresize_inode feature only works on filesystems up to 16TiB in size. After that, the meta_bg feature is used when storing group descriptors, so resize_inode is no longer needed/usable.

Comment: Thank you! That actually makes a lot of sense (there's another prior question of mine- I got more familiar with ext4 internals than I'd like) and is the case on other servers, but on this one I have ```has_journal ext_attr dir_index filetype needs_recovery extent 64bit flex_bg sparse_super large_file huge_file dir_nlink extra_isize metadata_csum```
No ```meta_bg```. However, both have ```flex_bg``` which should allow for the group descriptor data to go anywhere, arguably eliminating the need for either of the features. Why is it doing this I wonder? It seems tune2fs can't ```-O meta_bg``` .